# Mostrar datos de MongoDB cada cierto numero de registros con PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

tengo el siguiente problema, debo consultar registros de una base de datos de MongoDB, estos registros estan guardados a cada 2 minutos, lo que quiero hacer es poder mostrar los datos a cada 4, 6, 8, 10 minutos, etc... mi idea era utilizar el operador mod (%) de php, entonces para cada 10 minutos habia pensado en algo como:

```
(if ($cont % 5) == 0){
 //Mostrar los datos
}
```

Esta idea surge debido a que hago algo parecido en otra coleccion donde hago consultas, y los registros estan guardados cada 15 minutos y los muestro a cada 30 minutos, para ello hago esto:

```
(if ($cont % 2) == 0){
 //Muestra datos a 30 minutos
}
```

Es correcto hacerlo de esta manera o de que otra forma podria hacerlo?
Les agrezco sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es correcto. Tengo que reconocer que me ha costado un ratillo entender la pregunta, pero está chula. Ahí te va la solución para registros guardados cada 2 minutos (t*i=2*i):

```
$cont % 2 mostrará los datos cada 4 minutos
$cont % 3 mostrará los datos cada 6 minutos
$cont % 4 mostrará los datos cada 8 minutos
$cont % 5 mostrará los datos cada 10 minutos
```

En cambio, para registros almacenados cada 15 minutos (t*i=15*i):

```
$cont % 2 mostrará los datos cada 30 minutos
$cont % 3 mostrará los datos cada 45 minutos
$cont % 4 mostrará los datos cada 60 minutos
$cont % 5 mostrará los datos cada 75 minutos
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @David , ahora esto como podría implementarlo para que el usuario pueda elegir libremente esta opción, digamos que yo tuviera un campo de texto donde el pudiera escribir el intervalo. Por ejemplo si el pone 14 minutos, la operación fuera $cont % 7 == 0

Comment: Sería con $cont % $_GET['dato']/2, si te ves con fuerzas, prepara el formulario e inserta el código en una nueva pregunta, te ayudo con gusto a darle forma. Recuerda votar y dar ésta por respondida :)

Comment: Entendido, ya he hecho el formulario, acá está el enlace a la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244525/implementar-operaci%c3%b3n-mod-en-formulario-de-php                                                                     Muchas gracias de antemano @David