# Implementar operación MOD en formulario de PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

estoy usando un formulario para hacer consultas a una base de datos de MongoDB, cuyos registros de una colección están almacenados a cada 15 minutos, y en otra están a 2 minutos, en el formulario coloco un campo para elegir el intervalo de tiempo y en otros dos un rango de fechas, la idea es hacer la consulta de acuerdo al rango de fechas y utilizo el campo de intervalo para que me traiga los datos a cada 15min, 30min, 45min, etc. Para hacer esto hago uso del operador MOD de PHP, por ejemplo para consultar los datos a 30 minutos hago lo siguente:

```
if(($cont % 2) == 0){
 //Mostrar datos a 30 minutos
}
```

Actualmente esto lo hago con un grupo de radio buttons, pero ahora quisiera que esto fuera libre para el usuario y que el pudiera poner 60 minutos por ejemplo.

Aca dejo el codigo de mi formulario.

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Formulario de consultas</title>
        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Intervalo</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="intervalo" value="15min" checked id="rd1" /> 
                            15 Minutos</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="intervalo" value="30min" id="rd2" />
                            30 Minutos</label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="intervalo" value="1dia" id="rd3"/>
                            1 Día</label>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Periodo</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-group input-large" data-date="01/01/2014" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-view-mode="years">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" id="inicio"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">a</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control dpd2" id="fin" />
                    </div>
                <span class="help-block">Seleccionar rango de fechas</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert, te paso la solución en PHP7 que resuelve tu problema. Al HTML únicamente le he añadido las etiquetas form y button:

```
<?php
$intervalo_muestreo=15;
$cont=96;
if(isset($_GET['intervalo'])){
    if($cont % floor($_GET['intervalo']/$intervalo_muestreo) == 0){
     echo 'Mostrar datos cada '.$_GET['intervalo'].' minutos';
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Formulario de consultas</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Intervalo</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="intervalo" value="15" checked id="rd1" /> 
                        15 Minutos</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="intervalo" value="30" id="rd2" />
                        30 Minutos</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="intervalo" value="1440" id="rd3"/>
                        1 Día</label>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Periodo</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-group input-large" data-date="01/01/2014" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-view-mode="years">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dpd1" id="inicio"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">a</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control dpd2" id="fin" />
                </div>
            <span class="help-block">Seleccionar rango de fechas</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, por la ayuda, lo implementaré. Por cierto en caso de que quisiera cambiar los radio buttons por un input text, ahora la variable $_GET['intervalo'], tomaria el valor de este elemento, en vez de los value de cada radio?

Comment: Genial, gracias a ti. Mientras el name del input text también lo llames intervalo, como si lo pasas en un textarea, a php llega en la misma variable superglobal $_GET['intervalo'] Recuerda marcar la respuesta como válida y votar :)

Answer (score -1):

**puedes hacerlo asi:**

```
function interval($inter){
    @session_start();
    //configuramos un tiempo por defecto si no existe o tomamos el ya existente
    $_SESSION['time'] =isset($_SESSION['time']) ? $_SESSION['time'] : 0 ;
    // agregar un filtro para que solo acepte enteros
    $inter= filter_var($_GET['intervalo'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    // configuramos el $intervalo * 60
    $inter= $inter*60;
    // sacamos la fecha en formato unix
    $date = date('U');

    // validamos si el intervalo de tiempo cambio
    if($inter !=  $_SESSION['time']){
        // si cambio configuramos uno nuevo
        $_SESSION['time']=$inter;
        // y desconfiguramos la variable $_SESSION['intervalo'];
        unset($_SESSION['intervalo']);
    }

    //validamos si $_session['interval'] esta vacio
    if (empty($_SESSION['intervalo'])) {    
        // configuramos  $_session['interval'] y le damos el tiempo actual + el $intervalo
        $_SESSION['intervalo'] = ($date+$inter);
        // retornamos false para que no haga nada 
        return false;
    }

    // validamos que $_session['interval']  sea menor o igual a $date
    if ($_SESSION['intervalo'] <= $date) {
        // volvemos a configuar a $_session['interval'] con el tiempo actual + el intervalo
        $_SESSION['intervalo'] = ($date+$inter);
        // retornamos true
        return true;
    }
    // retornamos false
    return false;
}
```

**ahora como la utilizamos:**

```
// 3 == 3 minutos

if (interval($_GET['intervalo'])) {
    echo "ejecuto accion y espero " . ceil($_SESSION['intervalo']/60)  . "para la siguiente ejecucion!";
}

if (!interval($_GET['intervalo'])) {
    $time = isset($_SESSION['intervalo']) ? ceil(($_SESSION['intervalo']-date('U'))/60)  : "";
    echo "aun faltan: ". $time ." para la ejecucion!";
}
```